# How to create an own implementation of class in JavaScript and pass it a constructor

Tags: javascript, object, methods, this, prototype

Maybe such a question has already existed but I didn't found it and I still have a problem. I tried that:

```js
function defClass(obj) {
    const constructor = obj.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = obj;
    return constructor;
}
```

and then:

```js
const Person = defClass({
    constructor: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    voice() {
        console.log(`Hello, I'm ${this.name}`);
    } 
})
```

It works. But what if I want to use a constructor like this:

```js
const Person = defClass({
    constructor(name) {
        this.name = name;
    },
    voice() {
        console.log(`Hello, I'm ${this.name}`);
    } 
})
```

I think it is more similar to native realization. But I get an error: 'Person is not a constructor'. What is the difference between these two ways? Sorry for such a silly question, I just trying to figure out this fundamental thing. Thanks for any help.

Comment: are you intended to using object function constructor? if yes, then maybe this article can give you another point of view in OOP of Javascript. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/introduction-object-oriented-programming-javascript/

Comment: Just FWIW, JavaScript has had a [`class` construct](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) since ES2015 which is (now) universally supported in any vaguely-modern environment. There's no need for this `defClass` function.

Comment: If you're using ES6 method syntax, why wouldn't you use ES6 class syntax as well?

Comment: I know that ES6 has a class construct and I use it. I do my realization for some practice in prototypes, I just want to figure out how it works. It's all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Methods* - that is:

```
someMethodName() {
}
```

cannot be invoked as constructors - you'll get the error you're seeing. Make the method into a function instead:

```js
function defClass(obj) {
  const constructor = obj.constructor;
  constructor.prototype = obj;
  return constructor;
}

const Person = defClass({
  constructor: function(name) {
    this.name = name;
  },
  voice() {
    console.log(`Hello, I'm ${this.name}`);
  }
})

const p = new Person('foo');
p.voice();
```

Or don't use `new` when calling it:

```js
function defClass(obj) {
  const constructor = obj.constructor;
  constructor.prototype = obj;
  
  return function(...args) {
    const instance = Object.create(obj);
    constructor.apply(instance, args);
    return instance;
  };
}

const Person = defClass({
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
  },
  voice() {
    console.log(`Hello, I'm ${this.name}`);
  }
})

const p = Person('foo');
p.voice();
```